# need to waiting process in linux Operating system

Tags: linux, security, wait

Greatings to you first
I am a student at the university, and my end of study project is to master an information security protocol for autonomous systems
I have a task in this project
when I type in the command line "kill [pid]", the process starts automatically after a delay of a few seconds
how I can achieve this task and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

use systemd service

Create a file `test.service` under `/etc/systemd/system`, such as:

```
[Unit]
Description=test service

[Service]
User=root
Restart=always
# number of seconds to wait before restarting
RestartSec=5
# Change it to some meaningful processes
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 30000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start the service: `sudo systemctl start test.service`

Then if you kill the process, it will automatically restart in 5 seconds

Note: if you modify the service file, you will have to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart test` to reload the change